# magento redirect to cart after checkout

Tags: magento, checkout

i have a problem on my magento

(on online server)
when customer click place order button it direct back to cart

(on my localhost)
when customer click place order button it direct to success page and this supposed to happen

this is what i've done
first i test the magento on online but it direct to cart, then i download all the data and run it on my localhost but its run normal the place order go to success page but when i upload the same data that 've download to server it still direct to cart

what should i do?

Comment: have you configured the payment methods ans hipping methods for the live site in Live mode.There may be some errors on payment that may be redirecting you to cart page again.

Comment: no
the problem is on localhost the magento run fine but on the server not

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was related to missing `php-mbstring` extension on server.

You can debug the error by enabling `display_errors` in your `index.php` file.

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Then on your checkout page, you can check the error output on firebug or similar debugger.

[image: firebug console]

Comment: Hi Mukesh, i am facing the same problem in Magento2.01, i have enabled mb_string extension...but still have the same prob..any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This could be down to many things, but I would start with checking whether you have php-mcrypt installed on your server.  If it's not installed, navigating to system > configuration > paymnt methods in admin you will get an error warning that crypt could not initialise.

Comment: im not using any payment method its all by cash payment